# How to connect to node js server via electron, to edit files in the folder?

Tags: node.js, websocket, electron

I'm trying to make simple electron app where user would be able to login and remotly update folder with pictures in it and Mysql database. But I don't know how to connect to Node js server via Electron application.

Comment: You're looking for HTTP requests, exactly like other JavaScript code.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to node js via electron with HTTP?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Do you have any Docs or links I can follow beacuse I'm confused

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+http+request